# Lucene range query on tokenized string

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

If I have a tokenized string, e.g. "12345 12346 12347", would a range query work on that field?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about .net, but in Java this would produce strange results. For string range queries, Lucene uses `String.compareTo(String)`. So, for example,

```
"2".compareTo("10")
```

would result `1` which means that `2` is lexicographically greater than `10`. At the same time, `1` is lexicographically less than `10`. Is that what you want?